# How to get user edit form in mini panel?

Tags: theming, users, panels

Could you, please, explain me how to get user edit form in mini panel ? I need to replace standard user edit form and to do it in block but have some problem with that - it seems that nothing happens.

This is an export output of it:

```
$mini = new stdClass();
$mini->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default mini disabled initially */
$mini->api_version = 1;
$mini->name = 'use_profile_edit';
$mini->category = 'General layout';
$mini->admin_title = 'User profile edit';
$mini->admin_description = 'User profile edit';
$mini->requiredcontexts = array();
$mini->contexts = array(
  0 => array(
    'identifier' => 'User edit form',
    'keyword' => 'user_edit',
    'name' => 'user_edit_form',
    'uid' => '448',
    'id' => 1,
  ),
);
$mini->relationships = array();
$display = new panels_display();
$display->layout = 'flexible';
$display->layout_settings = array();
$display->panel_settings = array(
  'style_settings' => array(
    'default' => NULL,
    'center' => NULL,
  ),
);
$display->cache = array();
$display->title = 'test of user edit panel';
$display->uuid = 'a100b9d4-cbcb-467e-98d4-6b1b403d6b24';
$display->content = array();
$display->panels = array();
  $pane = new stdClass();
  $pane->pid = 'new-d4156689-563a-4ad9-af83-098a55f33f26';
  $pane->panel = 'center';
  $pane->type = 'form';
  $pane->subtype = 'form';
  $pane->shown = TRUE;
  $pane->access = array();
  $pane->configuration = array(
    'context' => 'requiredcontext_user_edit_form_1',
    'override_title' => 0,
    'override_title_text' => '',
    'override_title_heading' => 'h2',
  );
  $pane->cache = array();
  $pane->style = array(
    'settings' => NULL,
  );
  $pane->css = array();
  $pane->extras = array();
  $pane->position = 0;
  $pane->locks = array();
  $pane->uuid = 'd4156689-563a-4ad9-af83-098a55f33f26';
  $display->content['new-d4156689-563a-4ad9-af83-098a55f33f26'] = $pane;
  $display->panels['center'][0] = 'new-d4156689-563a-4ad9-af83-098a55f33f26';
  $pane = new stdClass();
  $pane->pid = 'new-33b3eb45-4af7-4e68-aee8-dafdafdfb78e';
  $pane->panel = 'center';
  $pane->type = 'entity_field';
  $pane->subtype = 'user:field_first_name';
  $pane->shown = TRUE;
  $pane->access = array();
  $pane->configuration = array(
    'label' => 'title',
    'formatter' => 'title_linked',
    'delta_limit' => 0,
    'delta_offset' => '0',
    'delta_reversed' => FALSE,
    'formatter_settings' => array(
      'title_style' => '_none',
      'title_link' => '',
      'title_class' => '',
    ),
    'context' => 'context_user_edit_form_1',
    'override_title' => 0,
    'override_title_text' => '',
    'override_title_heading' => 'h2',
  );
  $pane->cache = array();
  $pane->style = array(
    'settings' => NULL,
  );
  $pane->css = array();
  $pane->extras = array();
  $pane->position = 1;
  $pane->locks = array();
  $pane->uuid = '33b3eb45-4af7-4e68-aee8-dafdafdfb78e';
  $display->content['new-33b3eb45-4af7-4e68-aee8-dafdafdfb78e'] = $pane;
  $display->panels['center'][1] = 'new-33b3eb45-4af7-4e68-aee8-dafdafdfb78e';
$display->hide_title = PANELS_TITLE_FIXED;
$display->title_pane = 'new-d4156689-563a-4ad9-af83-098a55f33f26';
$mini->display = $display;
```

Comment: You should be using "required contexts" to start with.. What pages do you need this block on?

Comment: I've added 'user edit form ' as required content. Then I added 'user edit' base form to content. I need this block to be shown on front page for specific user roles in 'showcase' region. I still can't get it to be visible.

Comment: It seems that instead of 'required context' one should use simple 'Contexts' on the right. I managed to show the user edit form for specific user when put there 'User edit form' with some user uid. But I don't know how to show edit form for current user.